# Json Import fails - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, jayrock

I have the following class structure

```
public class AreaFields
{
    public List<Fields> Fields { set; get; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Value {set; get; }
}
```

When I export to Json using `Jayrock.Json.Conversion.JsonConvert.ExportToString(List<AreaField> obj)`, everything works fine. The problem is when I attempt to import it back to a list of AreaField, the native import fails. What I am trying to is

```
Jayrock.Json.Conversion.JsonConvert.Import(strJson)
```

Is there a way to maybe override the import method?

EDIT: Yes, jayrock knows the type of the object. My guess it has to do something with me serializing a list.

```
Export -
List<AreaField> list = GetAListOfAreaFields();
string sJson = Jayrock.Json.Conversion.JsonConvert.ExportToString(list)

Import -
List<AreaField> list = (AreaField)JsonConvert.Import(typeof(AreaField, sJson);
```

Exception - Cannot import AreaField from a JSON Array value.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're exporting a `List<AreaField>` but attempting to import an `AreaField` (singular). Try:

```
List<AreaField> list = (List<AreaField>)JsonConvert.Import(typeof(List<AreaField>, sJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

"It doesn't work" is not a good start. Exception? Wrong data? Does Jayrock know the type of the object?

```
AreaFields af = (AreaFields)Jayrock.Json.Conversion.JsonConvert.Import(typeof(AreaFields), strJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

List<> won't works, but array works. Like this:

```
AreaField[] list = JsonConvert.Import<AreaField[]>(sJson);
```